# How to "rough up" paths of stochastic processes in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm currently typing up notes for a stochastic analysis course and would like to substitute my hand drawn pictures by pictures created with tikz. I am familiar with the basics of tikz  but have the following problem: Very often I would like to draw a path of a stochastic process that has some special properties, for example a path of a 2D Brownian motion that closes a loop around 0. I would like to be able to draw the path smoothly using normal tikz first and then apply some kind of disturbance to it, so that it actually looks like a BM.

Here is a picture that explains what I would like to be able to achieve:
[image: smooth and rough path]

I'd like to be able to draw the blue line first and then turn it into the "randomized" red path.

Does anybody have an idea how i can achieve this? I don't really want to simulate paths of brownian motion until one comes along that has the properties that i want it to have...

Thanks!

Comment: decorate your path with `random steps` decoration

Comment: Maybe you could post an answer to your question? Or include code in the question which @percusse can adapt in order to post an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a small example I built using the suggestion by percusse:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, pgf}  
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\pgfmathsetseed{2236}
\coordinate[label=below:{$0$}] (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=below:{$1$}] (b) at (10,0);
\fill (a) circle (2pt);
\fill (b) circle (2pt);
\draw [blue] plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates { (10,0) (0,10) (-10,0) (0,-10) (15,20)};
\draw [decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=5pt,amplitude=10pt}] [red] plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates { (10,0) (0,10) (-10,0) (0,-10) (15,20)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The file looks like this:

[image: smooth and rough path]